# Is there a guide to use just parts of the Scala language?

Tags: scala, oop, functional-programming

Scala is a multi-paradigm language. Maybe because of that, its syntax is very complex. There are frameworks that use just parts of Scala, for instance, [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) is more FP. Other frameworks use Scala in a more OOP style (like Java on steroids). Are there any guidelines (or even tools) about using restricted sets of the language? For instance, how to use it in a more FP style?

Comment: Just pretend that `var`, `while`, and `scala.collection.mutble` do not exist.

Comment: [The Red Book](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) is a nice introduction to FP style Scala.

Comment: Follow the rules in Wartremover strictly: http://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html

Comment: "Its syntax is very complex" – Relative to what? Yes, Scala's syntax is more complex than, say, Scheme's or Haskell's; but it is significantly simpler than, say, Java or Ruby. As @Dima pointed out, there are exactly *two* pieces of syntax that make Scala non-FP: `var` and `while`. And both are non-idiomatic anyway.

Comment: This  [wartremover.org/doc/warts.html](http://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html) seems very nice. Are there other such tools?

Comment: Or rule sets, for other programming styles (Wartremover is for FP, correct?).

Comment: I think @ZiyangLiu should create an answer talking about Wartremover. If possible, including other similar tools.

Comment: Two other good linting/refactoring tools I'm aware of are scalafmt and scalafix. I'm not familiar with any of these to talk in more details, but they all have pretty good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter published "[Effective Scala](http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/)" in 2012 which is a guide for which parts of Scala they have found useful:

> While highly effective, Scala is also a large language, and our experiences have taught us to practice great care in its application. What are its pitfalls? Which features do we embrace, which do we eschew? When do we employ “purely functional style”, and when do we avoid it? In other words: what have we found to be an effective use of the language?